# Lock screen doesn't show current weather

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lock-screen, blu-win-hd

I remember some time ago the lock screen showed some picture with the current location and weather info there. Now it's just a blue screen with old location and old weather, which has remained the same for a couple of weeks. It shows the current date and the correct time however.

I don't remember having changed any settings related to the lock screen.
Where should I look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the weather app by Microsoft i.e) MSN Weather app, know that the lockscreen feature is no longer working now. It is a requested feature in the feedback hub. If you are using some 3rd party apps such as [Weather flow](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/weather-flow/9wzdncrdkl8t) do the following,

---

Check and change the following:

1. Make sure that the battery saver is turned off.
2. Make sure that the Weather app you use is allowed to run in background.

If these things are set correect then and yet you face the problem,

1. Change lockscreen to a photo or wallpaper.
2. Restart the phone.
3. Change lockscreen back to weather app you are using.
4. Restart the phone.

If you are facing problem after this then you may want to try another  third party weather app.

Comment: yes, I used MS Weather, it was there from beginning.

Comment: can you give a link, confirming that it doesn't work in lock-screen?

Comment: @Alex I don't have a link. I was using this feature for a long time too. It is not working for me after the Windows 10 update. I went to the feedback hub to report as a problem. I found that several others have also reported that this feature was not working in the windows 10 and have asked Microsoft to bring back that feature. Also after performing a hard reset the Weather app is not even showing in the lockscreen options.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the stock weather app (MSN Weather / Microsoft Weather). You can get the temp on the lock screen by adding it as one of the quick status entries AND making sure to set the detailed status to Weather also. Both are found on the Settings > Lockscreen page.

- "Choose apps to show quick status" set to Weather
- "Choose an app to show detailed status" to Weather

Or you could switch to a 3rd party weather app like Blue Skies or Appy weather (my 2 favorites).

EDIT: The reason I recommend setting both the quick status and the detailed status to Weather, is so when they fix the issue (with quick status) you will notice it. The detailed status currently works fine, and does not require the quick status to work.

Comment: what do you mean: adding it as one of the quick access entries?

Comment: Under Settings > Lock screen. If you scroll all the way down there is a section called "Choose apps to show quick status". This is where you can pick 5 apps that can display data on the lock screen. You have to put Weather as 1 of the 5. Then you also have to pick Weather for "Choose an app to show detailed status" right above it.

Comment: Detailed status I'm using right now, but adding quick stats doesn't work for weather, that was my question. I can add it or remove from this 5 pics, it changes nothing.

Comment: Correct, you can only get the detailed status right now, as there is an issue with the newer versions of the Weather app.

Comment: Then correct your answer